# Dismiss system title bar via code in UWP app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a fullscreen UWP app for which I'm setting the view's `FullScreenSystemOverlayMode` to `FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal`, as well as setting `ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true` to be able to draw in the title bar area as follows:

```
// Launch the app in fullscreen mode
ApplicationView.PreferredLaunchWindowingMode = ApplicationViewWindowingMode.FullScreen;

// Use absolute minimal system overlays
var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
view.FullScreenSystemOverlayMode = FullScreenSystemOverlayMode.Minimal;

// Extend our view into the system title bar area
CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
```

This does what I intend, which is launch the app in fullscreen and hide the start bar and title bar. To show the title bar, I can do a swipe in gesture from the top of the display to show a tab at the top, then swipe in again to make the title bar expand in.

I need to be able to dismiss the title bar when I'm done with it, but tapping on the app window does not always work. Sometimes it does, but other times it doesn't. Seems like inconsistent behavior from Windows. There have been times where it won't dismiss in my app or other fullscreen apps, and restarting Windows fixes the behavior.

I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing here that is leading to inconsistent behavior, or if this could be a Windows bug? I'm also wondering if there is a way via code that I can make the title bar hide itself again once it has been shown?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I don't seem to have StatusBar available to me. Maybe it isn't available in UWP? Is that a WPF thing? The status bar might be related, but it's actually the title bar that I'm trying to hide.

Comment: Now it clear to me, there was no question from my side. The status bar is only on mobiles and as UWP stands also for them, I wanted to ensure if you mean Status or Title bar.